# Elixir Testing with Docker-Compose UP

Tags: docker, docker-compose, elixir

I've created a simple Sonatype API client in Elixir that returns the repositories and the components of the repositories.

I now need to create tests in Elixir so that I can verify the repo. I am using docker-compose to start the sonatype container. I need the tests to start with a fresh Docker(sonatype) repo to work with, via docker-compose up, then verify that it doesn't have any containers in it. Then from there add one or more images, then validate that the images I added are present. As cleanup, I could delete those images. It must be an automated set of tests that can run in CI or a user can run on their local machine.

My question is how would I be able to do that by either a .exs test file or bash script file?

Comment: Not sure if I understood it right, but you can define a `service` in the docker composer named for example `tests`, that have a `depends_on` property where you put another service, like `sonatype`. You probably need to add something to wait for the sonatype container is up, and them start the tests with `mix test`.

Comment: Hello. Could you by chance give me a small example of what you meant by that?

Comment: I will add an example tomorrow.

Comment: ok thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can build a `docker-compose.yml` file with something similar to this:

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  my_app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    command: >
      bash -c 'wait-for-it -t 60 sonatype:1234
      && _build/prod/rel/my_app/bin/my_app start'

  tests:
    extends:
      service: my_app
    environment:
      MIX_ENV: test
      LOG_LEVEL: "warn"
    working_dir: /my_app
    depends_on:
      - sonatype
    command:
      bash -c 'mix test'

  sonatype:
    image: sonatype/nexus3:3.19.1
    ports:
      - "1234:1234"
```

Then you have a bash script like `test.sh`:

```
docker-compose build tests
docker-compose run tests

EXIT=$?

docker-compose down --volumes

exit $EXIT
```

I'm not familiar with Sonatype, so this might not make sense, and you need to adapt.

Comment: It makes since. I understand now. Thank you very much.